# Give dynamically generated canvas unique ID

Tags: html, html5-canvas

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'), canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = image.width;
canvas.height = image.height;
canvas.id = ;
canvasContext.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
container.append(canvas);
```

how can I give all my generated canvas' unique ID's

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just add a counter?:

```
var counter = 0;
...
canvas.id = 'something_' + counter;
...
counter++:
```

Or to you mean *unique* unique?

Comment: yes this works but I probably was not clear enough i want the Id's to stick with these methods the id changes on fresh I want an unique id as in different for others but not unique as in random, if that makes sense

Comment: Sorry Bro, still don't get it.